# MySQL - Return list of top 5 users, while including logged in user

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the users with the top 5 highest scores in a database and assign each user a rank, which I can then display in a high score table. I want the high-score table to contain a maximum of 5 rows, but I also want it to show the rank of the logged-in user amongst the other players. **Let's say the logged-in user is 'jennie'.**

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *, @i := @i+1 i,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT highscore) FROM users s
        WHERE s.highscore>=r.highscore) AS rank
        FROM users r JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER BY highscore DESC
    ) x
WHERE name = 'jennie'
    OR i <= 5
        ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

(Using MySQL 5.0.96). [Here is a fiddle showing off the query.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYsiCE1bXeTnR2HzoJkKiR/0#&togetherjs=QE3uqmqPwD) My issue is the query operates differently based on one condition:

**1:** If jennie **is** in the top 5 results, 5 rows will be returned, containing jennie amongst the other users.

**2:** If jennie **is not** in the top 5 results, 6 rows will be returned, where the last row contains jennie.

How can I use somehow truncate the list of top users in case **2**, from 5 users down to 4 users, so when jennie appears on the end she makes up the 5th row? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by doing some clever ordering. First we order by whether `rank` is <= 4, then by whether the user is `'jennie'` and her `rank` is > 5, and then by `rank`. This way, if `jennie` is outside the top 5, she will show as 5th; if she is inside the top 5, she will show in the appropriate position (because of the final order by `rank`).

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT u1.userid, u1.name, COUNT(u2.userid) + 1 AS rank
      FROM users u1
      LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.highscore > u1.highscore
      GROUP BY u1.userid) r
ORDER BY rank <= 4 DESC, name = 'jennie' AND rank > 5 DESC, rank
LIMIT 5;
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
userid  name    rank
4       harry   1
7       phil    2
2       james   3
1       sam     4
6       jennie  7
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6i6XYB6ZgHfiXfcWT7GB/2)

Output (for when jennie's score is 40)

```
userid  name    rank
4       harry   1
7       phil    2
6       jennie  3
2       james   4
1       sam     5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6i6XYB6ZgHfiXfcWT7GB/3)

Note I prefer to do ranking via `LEFT JOIN` queries, as variables can be problematic...

Comment: This is brilliant. I tried to solve this the last hour with `CASE` and conditions but without success. +1